# How to generate loop CSV file names with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I need to output CSV files in a loop. Using pandas

```
for i in range(1,int(len(feed_file_order)/2000)+2): 
    print(i)

    final_frame = final_frame.append(feed_file_order[u:(2000*i)])

    u=u+2000
    final_frame.drop(final_frame.index, inplace=True)

    final_frame.to_csv('C:\\Users\\7005243\\Desktop\\trail_i.csv')
```

I want my output csv files as trail_1, trail_2 etc.

Comment: dont understant what is your problem, to build the file name?

Comment: change `'C:\\Users\\7005243\\Desktop\\trail_i.csv'` to `f'C:\\Users\\7005243\\Desktop\\trail_{i}.csv'`, it should work. The problem was that `i` in your case was the character i and not the variable `i`i

Comment: @Tacratis f-strings are great, but they available only from Python 3.6 onwards.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you are of course correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the last line of the loop to:

```
final_frame.to_csv('C:\\Users\\7005243\\Desktop\\trail_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

The `format` function will take care of putting the current value of `i` where the `{}` is.

Answer (score 1):

```
final_frame.to_csv('C:\\Users\\7005243\\Desktop\\trail_'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

You are adding `i` inside the string which is wrong. It's a variable which should change, so isolate it.